# Open a PDF file with c#

Tags: c#

I'm working on a C # application that automatically opens a PDF file when I press a button on a windows form.

Here is my code:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"Stock\171457\money.pdf");
```

It works perfectly. But in this case I already know the name  of the file `money.pdf` to open. But for example if I want to open a file with a different name that I do not know? That is, I want to open the file independently of its name.

Comment: But which file do you want to open then?

Comment: You'll always need to know which file to open. There's no getting around that. You can always prompt the user for the filename before opening it though.

Comment: You could try to search a pdf in a specific folder to get the name ```string[] allfiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("path/to/dir", "*.pdf", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories); //foreach ... ```

Comment: Something like tis does not work? (@"Stock\171457\*.pdf")

Comment: FrankM thanks, Can you give a lexample please.

Comment: @BRBL he did give you an example. There's also an answer from someone else below.

Comment: ```FileSystemWatcher``` is also a promising thing, if you want to open it as soon it is created. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i thought of something like this:

```
// create baspath for the search
string basepath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Stock", "171457");
// getting the files form th OS
string[] allfiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(basepath, "*.pdf", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
// security check, since it will open all files
if (MessageBox.Show($"You are going to open {allfiles.Count()} files. Continue?","",MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.OK)
{
    foreach (var item in allfiles)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the pdf files are available under the directory/folder "Stock\171457\" or you would at least need to know the location of the pdf files that you want to open. 
1. So first get all the list of all the pdf files names from the folder.

```
private string[] pdfFiles = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Documents", "*.pdf")
                                     .Select(Path.GetFileName)
                                     .ToArray();
```

2. Call the start method with the file name from the previous step.